# How to change a column value in csv dynamically

Tags: java, selenium, csv, jenkins, supercsv

I have a CSV file like below

```
SoftwareID,SoftwareDescription,SoftwareName,SoftwareVersion,SoftwareLifeCycleStage,SoftwareCodeBase,SoftwareTags,SoftwareSeverity
TestSoftware,This is Test Sample,AutoTestSoftware11,1,Concept,Large,java,Medium
TestSoftware,This is Test Sample,AutoTestSoftware12,1,End of Life,Very Large,java,High
TestSoftware,This is Test Sample,AutoTestSoftware13,1,Concept,Large,java,Low
TestSoftware,This is Test Sample,AutoTestSoftware14,1,Concept,Large,java,Critical
```

As you see, SoftwareName is unique. So, every time before execution, I need to change those values. But, I want to put my automation in Jenkins. So, I want to write code such that it could change the SoftwareName dynamically.

I did R&D on this and find below info.

1. I came across `CSVDozerWriter` in `SuperCSV`. Firstly, I read the CSV file to bean. Then, I will squeeze out the number part and increment that value. Then write that again to CSV. But, I find it very difficult.

https://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/examples_dozer.html

Can anyone help?

EDIT1: my main goal is to write a code to change the softwareName values

Comment: What is your specific question/problem?

Comment: I want code to change softwareName column values....

Comment: try out opencsv (http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Okay, will go through it....